# Initiating Buttons in an Array with OnClickListeners

Tags: java, android

This is throwing a null pointer exception. I've even gone as far as to declare 9-10 buttons to populate the Button array before calling the loop.

```
public void initiateNumberButtons()
{
    for(int x = 0; x < numberButtonArray.length - 1; x++)
    {

         numberButtonArray[x] = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(idArray[x].toString(), "id", getPackageName()));
         numberButtonArray[x].setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {      
                enableButtons();
                //numberPressed = numberPressed + numberButtonArray[x].getText().toString(); 

                Button b = (Button)v;
                numberPressed = numberPressed + b.getText().toString();
                runningTotal.setText(numberPressed);
            }
         }); 
    }               
}
```

This line specifically: 
The idArray is populated with legitimate button ids.

```
numberButtonArray[x] = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier(idArray[x].toString(), "id", getPackageName()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the idArray is filled up with regular ids - that means with integers from generated R class(e.g. R.id.my_button1), then you should use just findViewById() method without using getIdentifier(...).

```
findViewById(idArray[x])
```

The getIdentifier() method expects first parameter to be a String name of the desired resource, that you've declared in your XML layout resource file. e.g. "my_button1". Note that use of this method is discouraged as it is much faster to retrieve resources directly by its identifier than by its name.

Comment: Thank you for this super useful comment. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the exception. I've realized that instantiating Buttons like so: 
`Button oneButton,twoButton,threeButton,fourButton,fiveButton,sixButton,sevenButton,eightButton,nineButton,zeroButton;`

Renders them null... Any way around this?